# What range of sample size would increase the likelihood of finding significance in a 2x3 chi square?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

What range of sample size would increase the likelihood of finding significance in a 2x2 chi square? I did not find significant relations between artists (n=36) and non artists (n=20) on 2 levels of mood (mild or severe disorder) with more than 5 in each cell.

Comment: This question need more information because the answer depends on just how non-independent the data are (as well as a number of assumptions).  What are the values in the table?  BTW, is it a 2 by 2 table (as in the question) or a 2 by 3 table (as in the title)?

Answer (score 3):

A few thoughts:

- it's always possible that there just isn't a relationship between them;
- you don't want to just add more data to an existing dataset if at first you don't have 'significance', that invalidates the test--so you would need to gather a whole new sample;
- at least with a t-test, you maximize power if you have equal $n$ in your groups, I'm pretty sure that's true for chi-squared as well--so it would probably be best to try to get equal numbers of artists & non-artists;
- it's better to think in terms of *effect size* than 'significance'--an appropriate effect size for a 2x2 frequency table is the [odds ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio):
  $$
  \text{odds}_{\text{severe},A}=\frac{p(s)}{(1-p(s))}
  $$
  $$
  \text{odds ratio}=\frac{\text{odds}_{\text{severe},A}}{\text{odds}_{\text{severe},notA}}
  $$
  your best bet is to figure out what the odds ratio is for your data, and how big of an odds ratio do you care about--only then is it even *possible* to determine what sample size will afford what level of power.

Comment: Hi gung - just curious, any reason you prefer the odds ratio to a phi correlation?  It seems simpler to me.

Comment: @rolando2, phi is fine. With a 2x2, the odds ratio dovetails quite cleanly with power analyses. Also, learning to think in these terms will really put you ahead in the game, eg, the odds ratio is important in understanding logistic regression.

Comment: @gung- yeah, but try telling that to a business client :-)